# Make V global definition means

Tags: makefile, openwrt

Usually I use V=99 when compile my system in order to see the output in verbose mode, my question is related at the 'V' variable, which other type of loggin level can I use with that ?

I analyze a Makefile and I would like see what it is doing, but with V=99 it is really difficult.

Thanks a lot,

Pietro.

Comment: How big is the makefile? Is it small enough to post?

Comment: no is not, I thought was a general question